# Branched Site Deployment Problems

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cassini

I have branched some code on my dev machine for an ASP.NET Webforms app. .NET 4.0. 
The working copy (original) runs on IIS 7 localhost in an IIS Application.

I thoguht I would keep things simple and configured the branch site to run in Cassini. The page that rendered was a grey page with Diagnose Connection Problems button. It had a heading "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Fiddler revealed a 302 reponse code. No idea why a redirect is occurring.

So, not wanting to waste time, I changed the configuration to use IIS 7, created a new IIS Application for it.

The exact same result when trying to run the app. So, the result is common, regardless of whether I use IIS 7 or Cassini.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there something I'm forgetting to configure in the application.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this now. I'm not surprised that no-one answered, as this was a really weird scenario with a fix that does not obviously address the issue.

I had to do two things:

1 - delete the Global.asax and create a new one, making sure that it inherits from the Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication class.
2 - in the RadScriptManager (a Telerik component), change the RadScriptReferences to normal ScriptReferences.

I have no idea why these changes were required. But they worked.